# MSVC 12 Show where a library is being required

Tags: c++, msvc12

TL;DR Is there a flag or something that will tell msvc to print out which library/object file requires a given library?

say I get an error message like:

```
LNK1104 fail to open file: boost_thread-vc120-mt-gd-1_56.lib
```

I expect this because I haven't told msvc where to find that. But, let's say I want to know **why do I need that?**.

In other words, let's say I'm linking against `foo.lib` `bar.lib` and I've got a bunch of code in my project. Will msvc show me whether it's `foo.lib`, `bar.lib`, or my own code that needs it?

Comment: Adding [`/VERBOSE:LIB`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) might show you what you're looking for.

Comment: Almost. Turns out VERBOSE:REF gave me what I needed, but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding /VERBOSE:REF shows which object files reference which symbols in which libraries, all in a nice indented fashion. This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual C++ additional libraries can be specified with [#pragma comment(lib, "libname.lib")](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0aews7.aspx) instruction in source code. It may be placed in library headers and is applied when header is included in application sources.

Comment: Does this answer the question? I'm not asking how to include a library. I'm asking how to introspect dependencies.

Comment: That's how this message is generated by boost. i.e. library authors manually added pragma with library name to headers. Without it you would get usual unresolved external symbol errors.

Comment: Ok, I see how it is relevant. I could search the boost source for such a comment.
I don't think it answers the question though. I want to know which of my dependencies is causing that boost library to be needed.